# Checking if the element exists if so, then executing the action

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with the below mentioned function, can someone explain to me why the function continues to look for the tag_delete element even though there is an exception. This element is not present when there is no tag_loc. thank you for your help.

```
def remove_tags(browser, tag_delete, tag_loc):
    try:
        tag = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, tag_loc))
        )
    except TimeoutException:
            cancel = browser.find_element(By.ID,"i2329")
            cancel.click()
    else:
            delete_tag=browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, tag_delete)
            delete_tag.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            tag_apply=browser.find_element(By.ID,"i2328")
            tag_apply.click()
```

I have tried modifying the script in various ways. Each time I get the same error, but I don't know why, but the function deletes all the tags (even if they don't meet the tag_loc condition) as if it wasn't looking for this variable at all.

Comment: How do you know that the function continues to look for the tag_delete element even though there is an exception?

Comment: Is the exception a `TimeoutException` or a different one?

Comment: I know because it throws the error Unable to locate element: css-1fdajkb:nth-child(1) svg (this is the tag_delete variable). And also if there are other tags in the field it deletes them. The problem is that all the tags on the page have the same delete_tag. The only thing that differs is the title (to which the path is given in the tag_loc variable)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you are trying to do, but it seems weird to me that you don't use at all the element 'tag' you found in your try.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just starting my python adventure. I have received a task to write a script that performs some actions on a web page. The function was to check for the existence of a tag (tag_loc) after the title, if not then it was to press cancel, if the tag existed then it was to move on and execute the rest of the code (delete_tag is where the element deleting the tag is located on the page). The 'tag' is here because I have tried various methods of how to get around this problem, I realise it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue and ensure that the code within the **else** block is only executed when the **tag_loc** condition is met, you should restructure your code like this:

```
def remove_tags(browser, tag_delete, tag_loc):
try:
    tag = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, tag_loc))
    )
    delete_tag = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, tag_delete)
    delete_tag.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    tag_apply = browser.find_element(By.ID, "i2328")
    tag_apply.click()  
except TimeoutException:
    cancel = browser.find_element(By.ID, "i2329")
    cancel.click()
```

Comment: I tried that too. But I have found a solution. It was enough to apply the NoSuchElementException and everything works. In a previous function that worked on a similar basis, the TimeOut exception worked fine. Thank you all for your help. I still have a lot to learn.